# What adjective describes a material which transmits little or no light?

Tags: meaning, adjectives, ambiguity

I am trying to search online for materials with specific properties, including the ability to block light. I thought that **opaque** was the appropriate term for this, but I am finding that in common usage, people (and search engines) use it as a synonym of **translucent**, or light scattering.

What word should I be using?

Comment: Opaqueness blocks all light completely 100%. Trust that.

Comment: _Opaque_ means transmitting no light; _translucent_ means transmitting some light, but no images; _transparent_ means transmitting coherent images. Some people may be using _opaque_ in a special way to describe certain materials, like opaque stockings, which don't actually block light, but are different from transparent or colored stockings. Certainly almost everything is opaque, after all -- including plants, animals, and all human property, not to mention the earth. Translucency is unusual.

Comment: @ermanen Well it does seem to be essentially the same question. I lack SE experience, is there a way to merge duplicate questions?

Comment: @AdamWeston Yes, the way is closing the question as duplicate by voting; and when it is closed, the link of the other question appears at the top. You can read more details here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates